# Voltage divider for 14.8 V Li-po to power 7.4 V servos

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider, lipo

I'm wondering if there's a more straightforward solution than using a step-down converter for my robot. The robot is mobile, so it needs to run on rechargeable batteries (Li-po).

I'm using a Jetson Xavier NX as controller, which accepts 9-20 V input, and it's got 4 x 7.4 V servos (6-8.4 V range), and some other power-hungry peripherals, but they run off the 5 V that the Jetson gives out.

I've googled voltage divider, and used a 'voltage divider calculator'. It looks like I literally just use any two of the same resistors. Surely some voltage is dropped across the resistors? If I can still get >6 V from the divide, the servos will run.

It's also more complicated, because I use a PCA9685 (16 x PWM outputs) to control the servos, so all of the servos are on the same power lines.

Can someone wiser than me look at my drawing, and tell me if this would work?  If it would, what resistors could I use to get >6 V?

[image]

Comment: Do not use voltage dividers to power anything. Voltage dividers are only good when there is no current being drawn. You need a regulator.

Comment: Thanks, oh well.  Seemed too good to be true

Comment: A linear regulator can be used - but it will only be Vout/Vinx 100% efficient. At 12 vin that's 5/12 ~= 40% efficient and at 20v in its 25%. A switching regulator typically gives 80-90%>

Answer (score 0):

You have two similar choices, use either a Buck or SEPIC converter. That solution will give you a solid output voltage assuming it is rated to supply the current your load needs or more. They are relative efficient with the Buck converter typically being the more efficient of the two. Look at the specifications for the voltages and loads involved.